# Android Binder build error - error: undefined reference to 'android::defaultServiceManager()

Tags: android-ndk, linker-errors

Need your support to solve my problem to build sample "HelloWorldService" program with binder.

While building using `make` I am getting following errors.

```
target Executable: helloworldclient (out/target/product/pandaboard/obj/EXECUTABLES/helloworldclient_intermediates/LINKED/helloworldclient)
prebuilt/linux-x86/toolchain/arm-eabi-4.4.3/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-eabi/4.4.3/../../../../arm-eabi/bin/ld: out/target/product/pandaboard/obj/lib/libhelloworldservice.so: error: undefined reference to 'android::BBinder::BBinder()'
prebuilt/linux-x86/toolchain/arm-eabi-4.4.3/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-eabi/4.4.3/../../../../arm-eabi/bin/ld: out/target/product/pandaboard/obj/lib/libhelloworldservice.so: error: undefined reference to 'android::Parcel::enforceInterface(android::String16 const&, android::IPCThreadState*) const'
prebuilt/linux-x86/toolchain/arm-eabi-4.4.3/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-eabi/4.4.3/../../../../arm-eabi/bin/ld: out/target/product/pandaboard/obj/lib/libhelloworldservice.so: error: undefined reference to 'android::Parcel::readCString() const'
prebuilt/linux-x86/toolchain/arm-eabi-4.4.3/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-eabi/4.4.3/../../../../arm-eabi/bin/ld: out/target/product/pandaboard/obj/lib/libhelloworldservice.so: error: undefined reference to 'android::Parcel::writeCString(char const*)'
prebuilt/linux-x86/toolchain/arm-eabi-4.4.3/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-eabi/4.4.3/../../../../arm-eabi/bin/ld: out/target/product/pandaboard/obj/EXECUTABLES/helloworldclient_intermediates/main_helloworldclient.o: in function main:packages/apps/HelloWorldService/helloworldclient/main_helloworldclient.cpp:24: error: undefined reference to 'android::defaultServiceManager()'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [out/target/product/pandaboard/obj/EXECUTABLES/helloworldclient_intermediates/LINKED/helloworldclient] Error 1
```

Please help me to fix this issue, Let me know if detailed info is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the Fix for the Build error.

Added the shared binder lib entry to my Android.mk file

"**LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES += libbinder**"

Able to build without any error.